# Cannot add cordova android platform in windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

> E:\Document\Cordova\cord5>**cordova platform add android**
>
> Creating android project... Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code
>   ENOENT
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\jitendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)

I have checked JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME,ANDROID_HOME,NODE_HOME environment variables  which are fine.I made sure of setting android tools and perfom-tools in env variables as well.I have  extensively googled it but none of the solution had worked for me..

Can anybody please help me??

Thank you
Jitendra

Comment: try to run `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` (replace 3.3.0 with 3.4.0 if you're using cordova 3.4) in a cmd window an let us know what it displays. Or add the -d arg to have more info : `cordova -d platform add android`

Comment: E:\actiworks\Cordova\cord7>%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\check_reqs.bat
[Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.]

Comment: But ant is installed successfully E:\actiworks\Cordova\cord7>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

Comment: Well that's very strange, check_reqs launches `ant -version` and should display the message you have only if it fails. You can check the code in the file %userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js, in the block `module.exports.check_ant` to see what it does in 3.4 (I am still in 3.3). You can try to patch the file to call `d.resolve();` in all cases (skip the test).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried to execute check_reqs.js from node 
> var a= require("./check_reqs.js");
undefined
> a
{ get_target: [Function],
  check_ant: [Function],
  check_java: [Function],
  check_android: [Function],
  run: [Function] }
and 
> a.check_ant();
[object Object]

I tried to do same thing in mac where 
I had same problem as mentioned above but
sudo cordova platform add android executed succesfully in mac.

In windows 7 64 bit I tried cmd with run as administrator but didn't worked at all.
I think it seems to be security issue..Don't know how could i solve in windows...??

Comment: @jitendra have u found the solution ?

Comment: @PiyushKashyap sorry I was not able to manage in windows so I tried in ubuntu 13 and had same issues but I installed all lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 these are 32 bit libraries which need to be installed in 64 bit ubuntu to run android SDK as far as I read along with sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 and problem was solved in ubuntu.Did you found any improvement on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that both the Android SDK is installed and that both the tools and platform-tools folders are in your PATH.

In my case, those paths are:

> C:\Users\moryl\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
>
> C:\Users\moryl\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Go to a command prompt and run the "path" command to see your executable path.  Edit the system path in the "System Properties" control panel applet by clicking on the "Advanced" link in the left hand column, then "Environment Variables" button at the bottom of the "Advanced" tab.  Slightly easier to get to by just typing "environment" in the Start menu search text box.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael.I have tired execution all related enviornment vairables but its not working at all.. E:\Document\Cordova\cord5>PATH
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Ruby200\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\mongodb\bin;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\Users\jitendra\AppDa
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\adt\sdk\tools;C:\adt\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt\sdk\tools\lib\x
ra\AppData\Roaming\npm;